# How to create a STL vector/array inplace from shared memory?

Tags: c++, memory, stl, shared

I maintain a C++ application created long ago in C++98.
It uses shared memory for historical reasons.

This shared memory holds a variety of lists but all accesses to them is via raw pointers without any range checking.

This of course is rather unsafe and easily leads to overwriting data by poking into memory areas that are part of another list.

I tried to find a way to create STL vectors or arrays which use the data in the shared memory but provide me with the range checking of the containers.
So far, I found no way to do that.

Sorry, no code yet...

Does anyone have an idea how to do that?

Comment: You need a custom allocator.

Comment: If you cannot properly access data through pointers I hardly doubt `std::vector` will help

Comment: You can still go out of bounds of a `std::vector`. And creating custom allocators isn't trivial. You might be better of by creating a simple API for the shared-memory access and force all existing code to use that instead of the pointers. Then you can easily enforce bound-checking.

Comment: What you want is more like a [`span`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span) than a vector, unless you also want to manage the memory with it.

Comment: I suggest you look into Boost.Interprocess. It's a bit hairy but works pretty well.

Comment: You can use placement `new` with `std::array`.

Comment: Well, for the moment I think I will follow some programmer dude and create a small class that does exactly that. "Forcing" all my coworkers to use it is impossible, but "convincing" might work... :-)

Comment: Well, so I implemented the wrapper for the one-dimensional arrays easily. It implements the [] operator so the usage is very similar to the unguarded raw pointer. Only the two-dimensional arrays are a bit cumbersome, since there is no [][] operator... Or at least I do not know how to implement it! :-)  So far I use an at() method to access it.

Comment: You can have, say `Array2D` class, which `operator []` will return reference to `Array1D` which `operator []` in turn will return reference to value.

Comment: @sklott: Thanks, it works like a charm. So I *was* too stupid... ;-)

Comment: One more thing: My IDE is Clion and the way this is implemented now  has a side effect: When I create a Wrapper like: Wrap1D<int, 100>myVariable(someAddress);, and then use it like myVariable[0] = 42; then Clion complains that the value is never used. I fear now that the compiler will "optimize" this by eliminating the statement, thus eliminating the assignment...